# "UWPHost.pdb not loaded" - Debugging Xamarin UWP app

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-debugging

I have a Xamarin app for which I have been debugging the UWP app on my computer for testing.

I've been having difficulties debugging. I keep getting a 'No Symbols Loaded' error which goes onto say one of the following errors:

> UWPHost.pdb not loaded

or

> wkernelbase.pdb not loaded

Typically, restarting or rebuilding Visual Studio will *sometimes* resolve the issue temporarily. As a result of this, development has been an incredibly painful process.

Any idea how this sort of problem can be avoided?

Additionally, if it's not the PDB errors I get this instead:

> Unable to activate Windows Store app ... 'The app didn't start'

These errors can happen with absolutely zero changes.

I'm new to Xamarin so I could be missing something blindingly obvious here.

Something I already tried was checking the 'Microsoft Symbol Servers' option via Visual Studio options.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

UPDATE:

I changed the following Visual Studio option:

```
Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable .NET Framework source stepping
```

This allowed me to see the following error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x7747C762 (KernelBase.dll) in Framework.UWP.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0x8007000B, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x03B40000). occurred

Comment: Focus on debugging your own code, there isn't much you can do with the host.  0x8007000B says what's wrong, ERROR_BAD_FORMAT, "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format".  Most typically happens when you try to load a 32-bit DLL in a 64-bit process, or the other way around.

Comment: UWPhost.dll is part of .net core runtime for UWP apps. Which Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform package do you use? try to update to [6.2.8](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform/6.2.8)

Comment: @magicandre1981 yep already using this version. Thanks!

Comment: @CiaranGallagher It seems you are lack of pdb files when debugging. Have you tried to cache them all using Load all symbols and then debug again?

Comment: I can debug apps without the PDB for uwphost. so ignore this